# Issue uploading image file to Supabase storage with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase

I'm having an issue with uploading an image to Supabase storage from my Flutter app.

Basically the upload works fine however it only uploads a blank image each time.

Here is my code. FYI i'm useing the flutter image_picker package to select the image.

```
  File file = File(image.path);
  print('file $file'); // File: '/mydirectory/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/98A6C1E0-14B0-481B-82CF-49803A0EB015/data/Containers/Data/Application/E07B33F6-7B5C-4EA0-AF78-84FF5A7E5BAD/tmp/image_picker_556716D5-69B1-485E-A7EE-39502A0F73C0-63547-0000EA70E7438D43.jpg'

  // Upload file to bucket "public"
  file.writeAsStringSync('File content');
  final storageResponse =
      await supabase.storage.from('public').upload(image.name, file);
  print('upload response : ${storageResponse.data}');

  // Get download url
  final urlResponse =
      await supabase.storage.from('public').createSignedUrl(image.name, 60);
  print('download url : ${urlResponse.data}');
```

Both the storageResponse.data and urlResponse.data are outputting as expected (ie getting a response from storage).

So as mentioned it's uploading but seems like it's uploading the wrong type of file. I can't download the image manully in storage nor can i view it with the url which i guess is because it's corrupted. Also it's says the image is 12 bytes in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  file.writeAsStringSync('File content');
```

looks like you are overwriting the file with a 12 byte string